# rails console error readline load error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having problem with the rails console.  It gives me this error when I try installing the readline module using:

```
yum install readline-devel
```

I'm working with Rails 3.1.1 on a fedora 14 machine.

```
    /home/led/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/completion.rb:9:in `require': no such file to load -- readline (LoadError)
    from /home/led/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/completion.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/led/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `require'
    from /home/led/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/led/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:37:in `require'
    from /home/led/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:37:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

ADDITION:

i tried installing readline via rvm following this link
[readline install via rvm][1]

and rails c worked but the problem is when reboot my system and tried again it appears to show this error

```
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find rack (~> 1.2.1) amongst [ParseTree-3.0.5, RubyInline-3.8.4, ZenTest-4.3.3, abstract-1.0.0, actionmailer-3.0.5, actionpack-3.0.5, activemodel-3.0.5, activerecord-3.0.5, activeresource-3.0.5, activesupport-3.0.5, arel-2.0.9, builder-2.1.2, bundler-1.0.10, cgi_multipart_eof_fix-2.5.0, daemons-1.0.10, diff-lcs-1.1.2, erubis-2.6.6, fastthread-1.0.7, gem_plugin-0.2.3, git-1.2.5, i18n-0.6.0, i18n-0.5.0, json-1.4.6, mail-2.3.0, mime-types-1.17.2, mime-types-1.16, mongrel-1.1.5, mongrel_cluster-1.0.5, multimap-1.1.2, mysql-2.8.1, mysql2-0.3.7, polyglot-0.3.2, polyglot-0.3.1, rack-1.3.5, rack-1.1.0, rack-mount-0.8.3, rack-mount-0.6.13, rack-test-0.6.1, rack-test-0.5.4, rails-3.0.5, railties-3.0.5, rake-0.9.2.2, rake-0.9.2, regin-0.3.8, regin-0.3.7, rspec-core-2.6.4, rspec-expectations-2.6.0, rspec-mocks-2.6.0, ruby2ruby-1.2.4, ruby_parser-2.0.4, sexp_processor-3.0.4, sqlite3-1.3.3, text-format-1.0.0, thor-0.14.6, treetop-1.4.10, treetop-1.4.9, tzinfo-0.3.30, tzinfo-0.3.26] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:761:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:758:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:758:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:742:in `activate'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:764:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:758:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:758:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:742:in `activate'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1211:in `gem'
    from /usr/bin/rails:18
```

Comment: See here: http://biztech.sheprador.com/?p=81 Uninstall ruby, readline, etc. and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install readline headers and libraries **prior** installing the Ruby interpreter (it is shown once you complete the installation of RVM)

You can see that again doing `rvm notes`

Answer (score 0):

Check that the readline gem is installed. The above yum command installs the readline library, but to interact with it, you need the gem.

If it's not in your Gemfile, add it, run bundle install and check again.